# Why I get compile error when using a recursive lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to define a recursive lambda.

In other languages, such as go, it could be declared as:

```golang
func main() {
    var f func()
    f = func() { f() }
}
```

Maybe it's caused by implementation with template?

```cpp
#include <functional>

int main() {
  std::function<int()> f;
  int a = 0;
  f = [f,&a]() -> int {
    a++;
    if (a > 2) {
      return 1;
    }
    return f();
  };
  if (f() != 0) {
    goto out;
  }

  out:
  return 0;
}
```

Here's my compiler:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: When posting question about build errors, *always* include the actual errors you get, in full and complete and copy-pasted as text.

Comment: By the way, are you sure you want to capture `f` *by value*? *Before* it's initialized?

Comment: I downvoted because the exact text of the compile error needs to be in the question to make this a good question. If it is added I will remove my downvote.

Comment: And don't use `goto`. Especially if it's totally useless (like in the code shown).

Answer (score 4):

You are capturing `f` by value. You want to capture it by reference for a recursive lambda. Here's an example recursive lambda:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::function<int(int)> factorial;

    factorial = [&factorial](int i) {
        if (i < 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        return i * factorial(i - 1);
    };
    std::cout << "5! = " << factorial(5) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Please don't create examples using `goto`, not even if the OP have it in their code. The `goto` statement is almost *never* a good idea.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the feedback. Removed OP's code and added an example without the use of `goto`

Answer (score 2):

`std::function` is fine in most situations, but if your recursive lambda turns out to be a performance bottleneck, then you can pass the lambda into itself, with an extra argument:

```
int a = 0;
auto f = [&a](auto&& go) -> int { //explicit return type is required here
  ++a;
  if (a > 2) { return 1; }
  return i * go(go);
};
f(f);
```

Note that `auto` in a lambda argument, which is needed to pass a lambda to a lambda, requires at least C++14.

Comment: That is neat :-)